# javascript prototype inheritance overwriting methods

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here's what I have now

```
var Proto = function(){
    this.up = function(){ alert('hello'); };
};

Proto.prototype.up = function(){ alert('world'); };

new o = Proto();

alert(o.up); // prints "hello"
```

I would expect this to print "world" since I overwrite the method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually, if the method is defined in the object then the prototype's method will never be invoked.

Comment: Explicit implementation > prototype | Also see [**prototype documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following snippet:

```js
var MyClass = function () {
    this.print = function logAttachedToThis() { console.log('hello'); };
};
MyClass.prototype.print = function logAttachedToPrototype() { console.log('world'); };
console.log(new MyClass());
```

Output will be:

```
MyClass {print: ƒ}
print: ƒ printAttachedToThis()
__proto__:
  print: ƒ printAttachedToPrototype()
  constructor: ƒ ()
  __proto__: Object
```

When invoking `new MyClass().print()`, the engine will first check whether `print` is available in the object itself. Otherwise, it will check in the prototype chain. So actually, `this.print = ...` is overriding `MyClass.prototype.print = ...`. Not sure *overriding* is the right word in this specific case though, I would use *hiding* instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how prototype chain works, firstly engine finds the function in the current object i.e, Proto object, as up() is available there so it will not search in the prototype. But if it was not written in Proto object then it will search it in the prototype.

Here is an article on [prototype and inheritance](https://conceptf1.blogspot.sg/2013/11/javascript-prototype-property-and-Inheritance.html) written by me.